# I need to learn professional PHP website development

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to make a website app using PHP. I want to make something pro. I want to use url masking to create something like `site/xyz/hello` instead of `site/abc.php?id=1&content=hello&user=xyz`.

I am aware of URL masking using mod_rewrite but I don't want to include individual pages by giving pre condition using `switch` in PHP. I've used code like below in handler.php file but in this case I have to add all conditions

```
$plink = explode('/',$_GET['p']);

//starts url masking
if (isset($_GET['p']))
{
    switch($_GET['p'])
    {

// pages set for common interface       

       case 'home':
       include "home.php";
       break;

       case 'about':
       include "about.php";
       break;

       case 'terms':
       include "terms.php";
       break;
```

I want to make it dynamic like Wordpress, Drupal and Joomla. I want automatic URL from database. Only layout will be fixed. So I want tutorials and any materials based on professional-level PHP - all things I learnt by myself by online tutorials. If anyone can get me anything, please let me know. I want to create a website like phpacadem, learnable and similar.

Comment: like stackowerflow, for an example. Everytime we ask a question, we get url like "/questions/'question_number'/'question'"

so i want to create something like that.

Comment: Google for "htaccess friendly url"

Comment: In terms of URL organisation, you're looking for "routing in PHP" - do a search on that, and you'll find loads. You can do `/index.php?p=home` or, if you can use `mod_rewrite`, this can be converted to just `/home`. In broader terms, you could try tutorials for Zend or Symfony to see how apps are built with frameworks.

Comment: @halfer, I know, but the thing is I want to make something like stackowerflow. Not that much bigger, but user based webs app where anyone can join and post data.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like you want route control and 'pretty urls'.

An MVC framework might be perfect for your use-case:

http://cakephp.org/

There are many ways to accomplish the 'professionalism' you describe, what matters is whether your foundation addresses the future needs of your spec relative to your use-case. Cakephp might be a good place to start.